# skeleton-typescript-webpack fails when running npm start or npm run build on Windows 7

Tags: npm, webpack, aurelia, webpack-dev-server

I'm running Windows 7 64bit with Node v6.5.0 and NPM 3.10.3. I ran `npm install` in the skeleton-typescript-webpack folder and all the packages installed fine. When I run any commands that call webpack though, I get the errors below.

When I run `npm run build` I get this error:

[image: npm build Error part 1]
[image: npm build Error part 2]

When I run `npm start` I get this error:

[image: npm start Error]

As you can see, the command that is run before the `npm build` error happens is concerning webpack, and same with the command that is run before the `npm start` error happens.

Anyone have an idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The skeleton skeleton-typescript-webpack uses TypeScript 2.0 for compilation.
This gives tries to compile adm-zip which is in the selenium-webdriver node module. And this gives an error on a break statement after a return statement.

The file .\nodes_modules\selenium-webdriver\node_modules\adm-zip\zipEntry.js gives the issue. You have to comment out two `break;` statements in the file on line 96 and line 115. After this you get a correct build.